# How to move a record from one model to another in Google App Maker

Tags: sql, google-app-maker

I have created 2 SQL models in Google App Maker. For simplicity sake lets say Model 1 has all of the information that can be added and edited for each of the records. Model 2 works as a storage model where once a record in Model 1 is removed it moves over to Model 2. The idea is that the individual can click on a "removed" boolean which will open a dialog page to add in comments for the removal and once complete the record will be moved to Model 2 for storage and will no longer be visible in Model 1.

Is there any way to do this? If you need more information let me know and I will try to provide it but the reason I cannot post the existing app is because the information is confidential.

Thanks for you help!

[image: Models]

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer: move to another model**

If you want to enforce users to enter a message, you need to forbid them to delete records through datasources:

```javascript
// onBeforeDelete model event
throw new Error('You should provide message prior deleting a record');
```

Then you need to implement audit itself:

```javascript
// server script
function archive(itemKey, message) {
  if (!message) {
    throw new Error('Message is required');
  }

  var record = app.models.MyModel.getRecord(itemKey);

  if (!record) {
    throw new Error('Record was not found');
  }

  var archive = app.models.Removed.newRecord();
  archive.Field1 = record.Field1;
  archive.Field2 = record.Field2;
  ...
  archive.Message = message;

  app.saveRecords([archive]);
  app.deleteRecords([record]);

}

// client script
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function() {
    // TODO
  })
  .withFailureHandler(function() {
    // TODO
  })
  .archive(itemKey, message);
```

If you need to implement auditing for multiple/all models then you can generalize the snippet by passing model's name and using [Model Metadata](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#ModelMetadata): `funciton archive(modelName, itemKey, message) {}`

**Original answer: move to another DB**

Normally I would recommend just to add and set a boolean field `Deleted` to the model and ensure that records marked as deleted are not sent to the client. Implementation of moving data between databases could be tricky since transactions are not supported across [multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239810).

If you desperately want to make your app more complex and less reliable you can create record's backup in `onBeforeDelete` [model event](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events) using [JDBC Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/) service ([External Database Sample](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/jdbc/) could be your friend to start with):

```javascript
// onBeforeDelete model event
var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPassword);

var statement = connection.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO ' + TABLE_NAME +
              ' (Field1, Field2, ...) values (?, ?, ...)');
statement.setString(1, record.Field1);
statement.setString(2, record.Field2);
...
statement.execute();
```

Why do you need JDBC? Because App Maker natively doesn't support models attached to different databases.

Comment: Sorry I think I may have not explained myself correctly. Its not that I have an external second database, I have a second data set in app maker, i have added a picture in my original question. All i need to be able to do is remove the data from the data called "Watchlist_Data" to the "Removed" data.

Comment: I was able to do what I needed using a query filter as a client script                            This keeps the data on the back end when i export and only shows the active user whatever is not removed.                                          
                                                                                                          var datasource1 = app.datasources.WatchList_Data;
 datasource1.query.filters.Remove_from_WatchList._equals = 'No';
 datasource1.load();

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I needed using a query filter as a client script                            This keeps the data on the back end when i export and only shows the active user whatever is not removed.

1. var datasource1 = app.datasources.WatchList_Data;
2. datasource1.query.filters.Remove_from_WatchList._equals = 'No';
3. datasource1.load();